How can I import a .js file from an external server into index.html on GitHub?
I have a HTML + JS website hosted on github. This website plots data from a .js file. A team member should be able to overwrite this file from time to time, without having acess to the website scripts. Therefore it would be great, if the .js file can be imported although it is located on another server. Is that possible?
Thanks.
I tried to locate the file in another git repository B and set the permament link to the file in the index.html in the other repository A, but it only works when repository B is public (which i do not want).

The answer is yes, but of course the host for the JS file has to make it public. If it's not public, then of course a browser won't be able to import it.

It seems it is also not working even if the repository B is public.

What exactly does "not working" mean? Browsers do the work of loading JS files for a web page, so via the browser "network" developer tab you can see the attempts to load every imported script.
